# Attr toggle with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, attributes, attr

I have a table of inputs which I activate and deactivate on double click. Now this inputs are pre-populated with some data from DB. Because the user have to press a button in order to update the DB once they double click an input and change, I would like to store the value of the input just in case the user decides to click another cell after changing without pressing the button I can then replace the value that was not sent for the original. I am using jquery to do this attr toggle to change the inputs readonly but my knowledge in jquery is limited in order to achieve what I want.[Here is some example code](http://jsfiddle.net/PnSdC/)

Thanks

Comment: I am not getting what actually you are asking , where is the save button here , is save button specific for each cell , Could you please properly split the posting into paragraphs and elaborate the problem you are facing , so that we can help you out

Comment: `attr` method doesn't return a boolean value. you can use `prop` method instead.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself properly. "This button" that is not on the fiddle, does a lookup to `.find` the input with the `class="active"` and grabs its value to do an AJAX.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain myself properly. "This button" that is not on the fiddle, does a lookup to `.find` the input with the `class="active"` and grabs its value to do an AJAX. Because of how inputs behave a user can activate a cell modify it and without hitting the save button move to another cell without know that the cell value did not get sent to the DB. Therefore my idea was to make  it so when a user moved from one cell to the other without saving the content of the old cell, intead of the old cell showing what they typed it would show the original content because they did not save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you're looking to store data before a user modifies it, and bring the data back if the user doesn't save the changes they make.

If I understood the problem correctly, I would use [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to maintain the old values. It essentially lets you keep key-value pairs in an html element, so it's fairly easy to keep a string backup for an input. Add this to dblClick to backup the value:

```
$input.data("backup", $input.val());
```

And add this to return it to the original value:

```
function backup ($input) {
  $input.val($input.data('backup'));
}
```

Comment: Ok you got my question :) Now as you saw I am using `$(this).attr('readonly',!$(this).attr('readonly'));` to toggle the readonly attr and honestly I am not sure exactly how that is working. so my next question would be, how do I know when the element gets deactivated in order to replace the data back to the original? BTW thanks!

Comment: It depends. Do you want the value to revert if the user clicks outside the input without clicking save? If that's the case, I'd add the backup code to a $.blur added to the input. Also, on hitting save, I'd set the backup value to the current input value, so if the user immediately leaves the box the value will just revert to itself.

Comment: I decided to go the `.blur()` route but I'm having the problem of determine whether the focus was lost to the button or not [code][1].                                                                [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/PnSdC/13/

Comment: Solved!! I was able to catch it with a setTimeout - `window.setTimeout(function(){
                                            if($('button').is(':focus')){ alert("button has focus");}},100);`

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm ..

Every line (tr) has it's own cache var

When editing one input ... it's primer value get's cahed in it's parent tr cache var.
If editing another input the first one get it's original value back.

```
$(function(){
    // jQ 1.7 for on method
    $('table tr').data('bak',{$node:null, value:''}).on('dblclick', 'input[type="text"]', function(e){
        var $input = $(this),
            $tr = $input.closest('tr'),
            data = $tr.data('bak');
        // No input yet edited on this tr/line OR same
        if(! data.$node ){
            $input
                .toggleClass("active")                             
                .prop('readonly', false);
            $tr.data('bak',{$node:$input, value:$input.val()});                          
        } else if($input.attr('id') != data.$node.attr('id')){              
                data.$node
                    .toggleClass("active")
                    .prop('readonly', true);
                // restore initial value for the previous clicked input
                data.$node.val(data.value);
                // backup bak with the new input double clicked and it's value
                $input
                    .toggleClass("active")
                    .prop('readonly', false);
                $tr.data('bak',{$node:$input, value:$input.val()});
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner of Jquery. You can try putting the input in some variable like

```
var item = this.value;
```

In your code where is the button?

Comment: I tried that but I could not figure when the element was getting deactivated. I tried something like `$(this).attr('readonly',function(){!$(this).attr('readonly')});` but did not work how I thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your question. Maybe a function like this should do what you need:

```
function toggleReadonly(o, force) {
    if (force != undefined) { //Force state: true: readonly, false: modifiable
        if (force) o.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        else o.removeAttr('readonly');
    } else { //Toggle current state
        if (o.attr('readonly') == undefined) o.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        else o.removeAttr('readonly');
    }
}

//...
toggleReadonly($(this)); //simply toggle
toggleReadonly($(this), true); //set readonly
toggleReadonly($(this), false); //set modifiable
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am doing the toggle the replacement of the data and finding when the element gets deactivated is my issue.